# ESXi 4.0 U1 Installable HP Customized or ESXi 4.1 Installable

Tags: vmware-esxi

Curious on which one I should install. This is going to be installed on an HP ProLiant DL380 G7, which did come with the HP Insight Ctl Mdl/DL Bdl. With this being the case should I install the HP customized offering? Not certain what the U1 means...or should I just go with the base ESXi 4.1 Installable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with the 4.1 installable - there's plenty enough HP-specific stuff already in the generic version already, sure you miss out on knowing a few temperatures sensor readings but 4.1 is really worth the effort, loads of cool new stuff in there - we've moved all of our ~8,000 hosts over already.

Comment: Sounds good...what does that U1 represent anyways...? Hopefully not a reversal of the rack sizing 1U, 2U...:)

Comment: @Aaron U1 is Update 1, VMware label the major sub version releases as Update X, e.g. ESX 3.5 Update 4 etc. I'd also vote for the VMware sourced package - updates on the vendor specific variants have been very slow and the benefits are limited.

Answer (score 1):

ESXi 4.1 is the latest offering on VMware for Enterprise Virtualization. ESXi 4.0 U1 (Update 1) is the older version of ESXi. Update 1 is like SP1 for ESXi 4. One of the main improvements in ESXi 4.1 is pass through USB support.

You will get the HP customized version of ESXi 4.1 [here](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPVM06). Click on **Receive for Free >>**.

You will need a HP account(free to create) to download. The page is for VMware ESXi 4 and higer. So select ESXi 4.1 for the list of items.